# Looking for a way to enable intellisense for Mustache

Tags: intellisense, mustache

I'm using Visual Studio, but if intellisense for Mustache is available on other editors, I would consider that as well.

I am using Nustache, the .Net version of Mustache. https://github.com/jdiamond/Nustache

Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for this as well, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope. Thankfully, I don't have to use Visual Studio anymore. Sorry.